# How i can change the minimum and maximum value in this aggregations price magento 2 graphql

Tags: magento2.3, graphql, aggregations

Request

```
{
  products(filter: { category_id: { eq: "14" }}) {
    aggregations {
      label
      count
      attribute_code
      options {
        label
        value
        count
      }
    }    total_count    items {
      sku
      price_range {
        minimum_price {
          regular_price {
            value
          }
          final_price {
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response :

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "aggregations": [
 {
          "label": "Price",
          "count": 2,
          "attribute_code": "price",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "Below 100",
              "value": "*_100",
              "count": 8
            },
            {
              "label": "100 and Above",
              "value": "100_*",
              "count": 2
            }
          ]
        },
```

Here 
products aggregations
price value has

> *-100
>
> 100- *

**How i can change to minimum and maximum value(Price) instead of (*)  in this aggregations**

magento 2.3.4 graphql?

*i tried with*

*settings path : stores -> configuration -> catalog -> layered navigation -> price calculation*

*Tried every options*

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem as well.  It's difficult to build a price slider without knowing min and max values.  I accomplished this by doing an override on Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm\Improved.  On line 72, you can see where they remove the min and max so they can be converted to *'s later.

I simply changed mine to read:

```
    $data[0]['from'] = floor($data[0]['from']); 
    $data[count($data) - 1]['to'] = ceil($data[count($data) - 1]['to']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove special char from price range in magento 2 grapql  from here vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Aggregation/Builder/Dynamic.php

Just add these lines on line

```
         if($from>0 && $to>0){
                $rangeName = "{$from}_{$to}";
        }else{
            $rangeName = "{$from}{$to}";
        }
        $resultData[$rangeName] = array_merge(['value' => $rangeName], $value);
```